# Internet Data Plans in Shanghai

Tags: cellphones, internet, shanghai

I am traveling to Baoshan, Shanghai and would be staying there for two months.
I need a good Internet plan as I am enrolled in some online platforms and need about 1 GB of data per day and connectivity on my phone. So what SIM and data plan should I purchase, and where should I purchase it from? I will be landing in Pudong Airport.

Comment: 1 GB *per day*?

Comment: Less probability of any such data plans which provide you 1 GB per day..

Comment: A thing to consider: Shanghai does not have unrestricted Internet. Will these online platforms be available at all?

Comment: You could buy the China Unicom SIM cards they sell at PVG int'l arrivals area. Those cards somehow allow you to access Twitter and Facebook and etc.